# Check input if value is empty be appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have input form and sticky menu whenever scroll page bottom of B element my sticky menu appears but I want to check if my input is empty than show if is not there is no reason be apper how to do that ?

my structure

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <ul class="sticky">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" class="input" value="">
            <div class="a"></div>
            <div class="b"></div>
            <div class="c"></div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:1020px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container>div{
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background:#f0f0f0;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin:100px 0;
    }
.a:after{
    content:"A";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
.b:after{
    content:"B";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
.c:after{
    content:"C";
    font-size:250px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    display:block;
    color:#999;
}
ul.sticky{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
}
ul.sticky:after,ul.sticky:before{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
ul.sticky li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
}
ul.sticky li a:hover{
    background:#999;
    color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

JS

```
  $(function() {
         $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".b").offset().top+$(".b").height()){
            $(".sticky").show();
        }else{
            $(".sticky").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

my structure I added input control like this;

```
$(function() {
    var input = $("input").val();
    if(input==""){
     $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".b").offset().top+$(".b").height()){
            $(".sticky").show();
        }else{
            $(".sticky").hide();
        }
    });

}
});
```

but didn't work.

[click to see demo](http://codepen.io/yedincifirat/pen/ALBJXG)

Comment: Your CodePen does not seem to match the code on here - you're missing your input and the script for checking the input value (at a quick skim-reading glance)

Comment: @GeoffJames is right the CodePen isn't updated, I had to add the input manually to the html and then edit your jQuery in order to solve this, be careful with this next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple, this code will check if the input is empty too and if it's empty will show you the sticky bar.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".b").offset().top+$(".b").height() && $("input").val() == ""){
            $(".sticky").show();
        }else{
            $(".sticky").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** By the way I recommend you to take a course about logic and jQuery in order to solve this kind of things, because people here is going to help you solve your problems, but they aren't going to write it down for you normally. There are really good courses about it out there, take some time and you'll be able to solve this kind of problems easily. Keep up the good work I know you can ;)